# Is it possible to set the mailer within a laravel mailable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a mailable, and I'd like it to always use a specific mailer. Currently, I send the mail like this:

```
Mail::mailer('smtp2')->to($recipient)->send(new AuthTokenMail());
```

What I'd like to do is set the mailer within the mailable, the same way I set the queue, like this:

```
class AuthTokenMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(int $code)
    {
        $this->onQueue('email2');
        $this->mailer('smtp2');   // doesn't work!
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Hi mankowitz! did you setup the smtp2 configuration in your mail.php config file?

Comment: Yes. I have mailers set up in the config file. I'm able to get it to work with `Mail::mailer('smtp2')` but not as part of the `Mailable` class.

Comment: For some reason it is now working as expected.

Comment: Nice to hear that! It the response was helpful U can mark it helpful

Comment: Can we make this work for Amazon SES mail driver? I was trying to configure it but it doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for you to be able to use the specific mail details you need to set it up in your **mail.php** config file. like this:

```
'mailers' => [
            'smtp' => [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
                'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
                'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
                'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
                'timeout' => null,
                'auth_mode' => null,
            ],
            'smtp2' => [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
                'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
                'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
                'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
                'timeout' => null,
                'auth_mode' => null,
            ],
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ];
```

Comment: Yes. I have this set up.